# Subscribe for instances list update in GCE autoscaled group

Tags: google-compute-engine

Is there a way to get/subscribe the/for running instances list in GCE autoscaled group.
Via gcloud tool, we can periodically call for the list, but I would like to subscribe for the list update.
I doubt that there is such API implementation for now in GCE(except project metadata), but I need to have such functionality in my application so I could write a logic on that.
Maybe someone has experience with a similar case or know any "hack" for this?

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge there is no method to subscribe to a list of instances in an managed instance group.

You will need to poll the managed instance group manually to determine the list of current instances.

`gcloud compute instance-groups managed list <NAME>`

This is a task that could be done very easily in Cloud Functions. At fixed intervals scan the group and email you the list in Json for example. The possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 0):

You can build this easily using (1) a pubsub topic "instance-group-changes" and (2) pushing events to this in your startup & shutdown scripts.

### (1) Create the "instance-group-changes" topic

```
gcloud init
gcloud pubsub topics create instance-group-changes
```

### (2) Modify the startup script for the instance group to send an addInstance event

**note:** be sure to add the "cloud pubsub api access scope" in the instance template

Use the meta-data service to obtain  the instance-id, hostname, etc.

```
TOPIC=instance-group-changes
instance_id=`curl -s  http://metadata.google.internal/0.1/meta-data/instance-id`
gcloud pubsub topics publish "$TOPIC" \
   --attribute 'event=addInstance' \
   --message "instance_id=$instance_id"
```

### (3) Modify the shutdown script to send a removeInstance event

```
TOPIC=instance-group-changes
instance_id=`curl -s http://metadata.google.internal/0.1/meta-data/instance-id`
gcloud pubsub topics publish "$TOPIC" \
   --attribute 'event=removeInstance' \
   --message "instance_id=$instance_id"
```

### Testing

Create the subscription

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions create sub-instance-group-changes --topic=instance-group-changes
```

Pull from the subscription

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull --limit  5 sub-instance-group-changes
┌─────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────┬──────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│               DATA              │    MESSAGE_ID   │      ATTRIBUTES      │                                                                               ACK_ID                                                                               │
├─────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│
│ instance_id=5396233750823583338 │ 407816607936940 │ event=addInstance    │ XkASTD4HRElTK0MLKlgRTgQhIT4wPkVTRFAGFixdRkhRNxkIaFEOT14jPzUgKEUaC1MTUVx1Hk4Qb1gzdQdRDRlze2hxO1kaAFMTUHRdURsfWVx-SgNRChFze2d1bVMQBwtBU1b55f_L9q0zZhs9XBJLLD5-NTJFQQ │
│ instance_id=5396233750823583338 │ 407816742842477 │ event=removeInstance │ XkASTD4HRElTK0MLKlgRTgQhIT4wPkVTRFAGFixdRkhRNxkIaFEOT14jPzUgKEUaC1MTUVx1Hk4Qb1gzdQdRDRlze2hxO1kaAFMTUHRcURsfWVx-SgNRChFze2ZxaFIXAwZCVFb55f_L9q0zZhs9XBJLLD5-NTJFQQ │
```